# number of permutation with k inversions

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dynamic-programming, permutations, mergesort

We are given two numbers N and K.

N <= 10^9.

K<=min{1000,(N*(N-1))/2}

We need to find numbers of permutations of ( 1 to N ) such that inversions are exactly K.

If N was <= 10^3. It would be a simple Dynamic programming question.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-permutation-with-k-inversions/

can we optimize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a sketch of solution (there might be some off-by-ones)

---

Looking at a permutation of $\{1\ldots,n\}$ is equivalent at looking its inversion table $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ where $a_i$ is the number of elements to the left of $i$ that are greater than $i$. Basically that gives you a bijection between $S_n$ and $\prod_{1\le i\le n} \{0,\ldots,i-1\}$ and the number of inversions of the permutation is exactly the sum of all $a_i$ corresponding to it (see for example Knuth TAOCP volume 3 for a nice development).

So the problem is equivalent to computing the cardinal of:

$$\{(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \prod_{i=1}^{n}\{0,\ldots,i-1\}, \sum_{i=1}^n a_i=k\}$$

This way, we find a DP algorithm with $n\times k$ states:

$$\text{dp}(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{\min(k,n-1)}\text{dp}(n-1,k-i)$$

Thus:

- When $n$ is small ($n\le k+1$):

$$\text{dp}(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\text{dp}(n-1,k-i)=\text{dp}(n,k-1)+\text{dp}(n-1,k)$$

So you can compute these in $O(k^2)$. In particular, we will need the following vector of size $k$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\text{dp}(k+1,0)\\
\vdots\\
\text{dp}(k+1,k)
\end{bmatrix}$$

- When $n$ is large ($n>k+1$):

$$\text{dp}(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\text{dp}(n-1,k-i)=\sum_{i=0}^k \text{dp}(n-1,i)$$

In this case $\text{dp}(n,\cdot)$ depends linearly on $\text{dp}(n-1,\cdot)$, the matrix being a $k\times k$ lower triangular matrix with nonzero coefficients being all 1-s. More formally, you can rewrite the previous equality as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\text{dp}(n,0)\\
\vdots\\
\text{dp}(n,k)
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&\ldots&\ldots&0\\
1&1&0&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&1&\ldots&1&0\\
1&1&\ldots&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{dp}(n-1,0)\\
\vdots\\
\text{dp}(n-1,k)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Just let me note:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&\ldots&\ldots&0\\
1&1&0&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&1&\ldots&1&0\\
1&1&\ldots&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now if you iterate the relation, you will get for any $i$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\text{dp}(n+i,0)\\
\vdots\\
\text{dp}(n+i,k)
\end{bmatrix}=
A^i
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{dp}(n,0)\\
\vdots\\
\text{dp}(n,k)
\end{bmatrix}$$

In particular:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\text{dp}(n,0)\\
\vdots\\
\text{dp}(n,k)
\end{bmatrix}=
A^{n-k-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{dp}(k+1,0)\\
\vdots\\
\text{dp}(k+1,k)
\end{bmatrix}$$

The vector on the left hand side is what we want ($\text{dp}(n,k)$), the vector on the right hand side is what we computed in the first step (when $n$ is small). So if we can compute the $k\times k$ matrix $A^{n-k-1}$, computing the answer can be done in $O(k^2)$.

---

Now let's see how fast we can compute $A^{n-k-1}$. I suggest three different ideas (I assume that you want the answer modulo some prime $p$):

1) Matrix exponentiation: if we can multiply $k\times k$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in time $O(k^\omega)$), you can use fast exponentiation to have a $O(k^\omega \log n)$ algorithm ($\omega =2.38$ nowadays). Actually, if you are fine with a $O(k^3 \log n)$ algorithm, this should be easy to code (with the naive matrix multiplication algorithm)

2) Polynomial interpolation: if you look at the coefficients of $(A^T)^n$, it looks like:

$$(A^T)^n=\begin{bmatrix}
P_1(n)&P_2(n)&\ldots&P_k(n)\\
0&P_!(n)&\ldots&P_{k-1}(n)\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&\ldots&0&P_1(n)
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $P_1, \ldots, P_k$ are polynomials with integer coefficients and $P_i$ is of degre $i-1$. They satisfy some kind of "generalized Pascal triangle relationship":

$$P_i(n)=1+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}P_{i-1}(j)$$

So it's possible to compute $P_i(j)$ for $1\le i \le k$ and $0\le j\le k-1$ in $O(k^2)$. We can find coefficients of $P_i$ by doing a Newton interpolation in $O(k \log k)$, so this should give a $O(k^2 \log k)$ algorithm.

3) Find a closed form for $A^i$ with the help of some well-known combinatorial objects. As I said in the comments, the polynomials $P_1, \ldots, P_k$ are close to Faulhaber's polynomials which can be computed in linear time. This might require some heavy handmade computation. I think it should lead to a  $O(k^2)$ algorithm.

Comment: I did not understand from "the matrix being a k×k ...". Could you please give me a little example?

Comment: @Learner007 You're right to be suspicious, because it's wrong indeed: it's a lower triangular matrix consisting only of 1 (if you write the vector $x_n=(\text{dp}(n,0),\ldots,\text{dp}(n,k))$, you have $x_n=A x_{n-1}$). So my answer is actually not very satisfying as such: you'll have a $O(k^3\log n)$ algorithm (or $O(k^{2.37}\log n)$ if that's a theoretical question), I need to sleep right now but meanwhile you can investigate what powers of this matrix $A$ are like (you'll get $k$ interesting polynomials in $n$ of degree $\le k$, not sure whether they are easy to compute)

Comment: My conjecture would be that the coefficients of these polynomials are computable in $O(k^2)$, because they are very similar to the Faulhaber's polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), which only involve Bernoulli's numbers

Comment: if I want to use this method N=6 and K=3 can you explain using this example?

Comment: @Learner007: I tried to be a little bit more precise (also I added description of a $O(k^2 \log k)$ algorithm). Tell me if that's still unclear (tbh matrices in LaTeX are a bit of a pain to write)

Comment: thanks. This is the best explanation.

Comment: @md5: you also can use the following trick: the value of $\text{dp($n$, $k$)}$ is $(0, 0, \ldots, 0, 1) \cdot A^{n - k - 1} \cdot (\text{dp($k + 1$, $0$)}, \text{dp($k + 1$, $1$)}, \ldots, \text{dp($k + 1$, $k$)})^T$. In other words, it is $f A^{m} s^T$ for some row-vectors $s$ and $f$ and $m = n - k  - 1$. Now, suppose that $\chi_A (x) = x^{k + 1} - c_k x^k - c_{k - 1} x^{k - 1} + \ldots + c_0 x^0$ is characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $m \geqslant k + 1$. Then $f A^{m} s^T$ = $f (c_k A^{m-1} + \ldots + c_0 A^{m-k-1}) s^T = c_k \cdot f A^{m-1} s^T + \ldots + c_0 \cdot f A^{m-k-1} s^T$.

Comment: Therefore, the values of $f A^m s^T$ (that is, the answers to the problem) satisfy a linear recurrence of length at most $k + 1$. Now, you can find the coefficients of the recurrence using Berlekamp-Massey algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp–Massey_algorithm) in $O(k^2)$ time, as long as you know values of $\text{dp}(n, k)$ for $O(k)$ first values of $n$. But as you said, you can compute these values upto some small $n$ in $O(nk)$ time, therefore precalculating these values takes $O(k^2)$ time as well.

This approach does not rely on specific properties of matrix $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the answers to this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372991/number-of-n-element-permutations-with-exactly-k-inversions
(in particular the part about Mahonian numbers)

Additionally, it seems that dynamic programming with memoisation runs in $\mathcal{O}(N\cdot k)$ [NB: I didn't actually check this, it's in one of the answers to the linked question]: if this is for a competitive programming problem, you might consider trying it: even though in theory $N\cdot k$ can be as large as $10^{12}$, the judge system may test/query only reasonable cases (it happens).